# Implicit conversion of 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I want to use a selector to call a func in my views controller, I want ot pass the number of a channel through to the func. This needs to be an Int, but I cant get the selector to respond correctly. How can i resolve this?

```
- (void)sendBusGetPar {
      [self.viewController performSelector:@selector(getBusParams:) withObject: self.bus.channelNumber];
 }
```

And this is the recieving func in the controller

```
- (void)getBusParams:(NSInteger)busChannel {
    [[self tcpControl] sendMessage:cmd(GETPAR) Module:module(BUS) ModuleIndex:busChannel
                           Section:section(CONTROL) SectionIndex:0
                              Unit:unit(FADER) UnitIndex:0
                             Param:param(POSITION) Value:0];
}
```

I know its to do with conversion and types but i cant see why i cant send a channel number through as an Int in this case?

I have also tried this but the selector doesnt respond so i assume its wrong?

```
[self.viewController performSelector:@selector(getBusParams:) withObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.bus.channelNumber]];
```

Comment: The `performSelector:withObject:` waits for an object, not a primitive. You should use `NSNumber` into the `performSelector:withObject:`, and redeclare also the `getBusParams:` to get a `NSNumber` as param and not a `NSInteger`. Or, create another one: `-(void)getBusParamsWithNumber:(NSNumber *)number{[self getBusParams:[number integerValue]]; }` and call that one with `performSelector:withObject:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`performSelector:` should not be abused for normal method calling.

Why don't you just call the method directly?

```
[self.viewController getBusParams:self.bus.channelNumber];
```

If your `viewController` has a generic type, cast it to the correct type:

```
[(MyViewController *) self.viewController getBusParams:self.bus.channelNumber];
```

Comment: This is indeed the best solution.

Comment: my view doesnt have visibility of its controller in code, they are decoupled so i cant use this method i just get No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'getBusParams:'

Comment: i imported the controller to the view and tried your second method, it still isnt calling the func but throws no errors, very confusing! I set a breakpoint and it never calls it...

Comment: Then viewController is probably nil.

Comment: @jcad: Just declare (but don't implement) a dummy category of `UIViewController` that declares this method. The compiler just wants to see that there is some declaration somewhere visible to the code it is compiling, so it can deduce ARC semantics.

Comment: @newacct Well, if a source want to call that method, it should import it's header. No need for additional categories.

Answer (score 1):

The method says *with**Object***. Unfortunately `NSUInteger` is not an object.

A suitable solution is to create an `NSNumber` object from the scalar integer and pass that.

```
[self.viewController performSelector: @selector(getBusParams:) 
                          withObject: @(self.bus.channelNumber)];
```

On the receiver side you need to cast it down with the `unsignedIntegerValue` 
property.

```
- (void)getBusParams:(NSNumber *)busChannel
    [[self tcpControl] sendMessage:cmd(GETPAR) 
                            Module:module(BUS) 
                       ModuleIndex:busChannel.unsignedIntegerValue ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this passed the error and caution checks, however at run time the selector doesnt work correctly (receiver is never being called) however if i CMD Click the selector in the view in my code, it follows to the func correctly, so its breaking at run time. would this be related to what im trying to pass or not?

Comment: Did you change the parameter type from `NSInteger` to `NSNumber` in the receiver method?

Comment: it wants me to add * after NSNumber if i change it, is that correct?

Comment: thanks, one more, in some locations where i use this func i + 1 or -1 from the sending value, how do i handle this? as it throws an error when i try to add to the value, for example...   [self getBusParams: channelSelected - 1];  where as if i remove the -1 it will work fine (but not be what i want)

Comment: If you call this method stand-alone you have to create an `NSNumber` object anyway, and you have to do the math **in** the wrapper:`@(self.bus.channelNumber - 1)`

Comment: @vadian https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html "An NSValue object is a simple container for a single C or Objective-C data item. It can hold any of the scalar types such as int, float, and char, as well as pointers, structures, and object ids."    You must pass &intVar(c pointer) as argument, but this it too low level for this question, but in performance (really low level), this make possible send an scalar without needing the overage of nsnumber parse nor create a wrapper for it.